# E: Unable to locate package yum

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying execute `ifconfig` on kali Linux so I got output `E: Unable to locate package yum`
So, I researched and found out that I have to run `sudo apt-get install yum` then I got output `E: Unable to locate package yum` so I cant find solution to install yum

I am currently running kali as follows:

````
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2020.2
Codename:       kali-rolling```
````

Comment: Corssposting is discouraged. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076608/e-unable-to-locate-package-yum

Answer (score 2):

Kali Linux is based on Debian, which uses apt as a package manager. Yum is the package manager used by fedora (before dnf) and still used by Red Hat and CentOS below version 8 (which relinks yum to dnf).

If you were trying to `yum install net-tools` (to get ifconfig) you would instead do `apt-get install net-tools`, if the package names were identical between distributions.

Comment: His problem is he is unable to install yum package manager in debian based os; kali here.